# validates_presence_of + :message shows the name of the field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

I'm creating a Rails app, and I have a model called `User`. In this model I have a boolean value called `isagirl`. A user must specify if it is a girl or not, which is done by two radio buttons. In my model I have this:

```
validates_presence_of :isagirl, :message => "You must be either a Boy or a Girl. If not, please contact us."
```

However, when I don't specify a sex, I'm seeing this:

> Isagirl You must be either a Boy or a Girl.

as an error message. The problem is that 'Isagirl' must not be there in the error message. How can I disable that? And no, using CSS to hide it is no option.

Thanks

Comment: for what it is worth, it's a good idea to support non-binary genders in forms if possible

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The way that I do this is to output the message without the field name.  For example, I have a partial that outputs the error messages after validation fails.

```
<ul>
    <% errors.each do |attribute, message| -%>
        <% if message.is_a?(String)%>
            <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
    <% end -%>
</ul>
```

Notice that this does not output the attribute.  You just need to make sure that all your messages makes sense without an attribute name.

Answer (score 5):

In one of my projects I was using [custom-err-msg](http://rubyforge.org/projects/custom-err-msg/) plugin. With it when you specify error message this way:

```
:message => "^You must be either a Boy or a Girl. If not, please contact us."
```

(notice `^` at the begining) it won't print attribute name when printing errors. And you can use standard `error_messages` or `error_messages_for` helpers.

Comment: FYI, this gem is now called `custom_error_message` and its available here: https://github.com/jeremydurham/custom-err-msg

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to omit the attribute name in the validates_presence_of function (it can be painful without dirty hacking) but I would use validate function to achieve what you want:

```
protected
    def validate
      errors.add_to_base("You must be either a Boy or a Girl. If not, please contact us.") if params[:isagirl].blank?
    end
```

I used specifically method blank? here because validates_presence_of is using blank? for the test you should get this same behavior.

add_to_base is adding general error messages that are not related to the attributes and this saves you from hacking the view.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the errors.add_to_base option. Without knowing what your layout looks like, that's going to be the simplest way to get a plain error message to appear.